# Checking if floating point number is completely convertible to binary

Tags: math, floating-point, binary

I know how to convert Integers and floating point numbers to binary. But some floating point numbers didn't have exact binary format. Like 0.5 can be exactly written as 0.1 and 0.25 can be written as 0.01 . But how can be sure if a number is completely convertible to binary?

Comment: Do you want to know how a human would check a number or how to write software that would check a decimal numeral?

Answer (score 2):

To be representable a binary floating-point format, a number must be a multiple of a power of two, including negative powers. For example, .375 is representable, and it is a multiple of 1/8. (1/8 is .125, and .375 is three times that.) There are additional requirements because the parts of the number must fit into the floating-point format:

A finite number can be represented in the common IEEE 754 double-precision format if and only if it equals *M*•2<sup>*e*</sup> for some integers *M* and *e* such that -2<sup>53</sup> < *M* < 2<sup>53</sup> and -1074 ≤ *e* ≤ 971.

For single precision, -2<sup>24</sup> < *M* < 2<sup>24</sup> and -149 ≤ *e* ≤ 104.

These values come from the parameters that specify the floating-point formats, such as how many bits are available for the fraction and exponent fields and how much the exponent is biased.

---

The following is a method to test whether a number meets the above criteria.

First, if the number has a fractional part, try multiplying the number by two until there is no fractional part. If you multiply more than 149 (for single precision) or 1074 times (for double precision), the number is not representable. If the number has no fractional part but is even, divide it by two until it is odd. Stop after 104 (for single precision) or 971 (for double precision) divisions. When you are done multiplying or dividing, look at the absolute value of the remaining number. If it is greater than or equal to 16,777,216 (for single precision) or 9,007,199,254,740,992 (for double precision), the number is not representable. Otherwise, it is.

(Tip: When doing the multiplication step with a number in decimal, if the fraction part ever ends in a digit other than 5, the number is not representable. E.g., .4 and .24 are not representable. .5, .25, and .625 are, although .525 is not.)

Answer (score 0):

If you have large integer arithmetic available, rewrite `xxx.yyy` as a fraction `xxxyyy/10^n` where n is length (number of digits) of fraction part yyy.

You convert decimal representation of numerator and denominator of above fraction to binary, then reduce the fraction:

- compute gcd(xxxyyy,10^n),
- reducedNumerator=xxxyyy/gcd(xxxyyy,10^n),
- reducedDenominator=10^n/gcd(xxxyyy,10^n)

if reducedDenominator is divisible by 5 (remainder is zero) then the number is not representable in binary, else it is, and the float can be represented in the form
`sign*integerSignificand*2^biasedExponent`

But in most languages, the number of bits of significand and the range of exponent are limited.

Let's take a look at numerator absolute value first, (I presume not 0) and extract

- `nh` = rank of highest bit set to 1,
- `nl` = rank of lowest bit set to 1

`nh+1-nl` gives you the number of bits (binary digits) required to represent the significand, it must be under the limit
For example, in IEEE 754 double precision: `nh+1-nl<=53` or `nh-nl<53`

Now let's look at denominator, if not divisible by 5, it is a power of two 10....0, so we can also rewrite the divisibility test: take

- `dh` = rank of highest bit set to 1
- `dl` = rank of lowest bit set to 1

If dh is not equal to dl, then the number is not representable in binary.
If `dh==dl`, you must have `nh-dh` remaining in certain range, but also `nl-dh`.

For example in IEEE 754 double precision: `-1074 <= nl-dh` and `nh-dh <= 1023`

What would be interesting and more simple if you are using IEEE 754 formats, is to know whether the conversion function `atod` or `atof` as provided by libc or the equivalent provided by your language will correctly raise the IEEE 754 inexact flag, and how you can access this flag in your language...